# Azure Application Gateway Rule Flexibility

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

We are looking to use the Azure Application Gateway to do some clever routing of requests, and I would like to know whether or not the product is flexible enough to do the following:

If source IP is in a given sub-net (say `SN-A`) **AND** the URL ends in `/foo/*` then route to Pool *B* otherwise route to Pool *A*.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible today, source IP routing is not supported.